# usb-c HDMI adapter won't work over usb-c hub

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, hdmi

When I plug my generic usb-c HDMI adapter directly into the USB port, I get this on `lsusb`

```
Bus 003 Device 031: ID 9636:9311 USB C   USB C Video Adaptor
```

and immeditaly I see the laptop screen in the TV

When I plug over the usb-c hub, I get this on `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 036: ID 9636:9311
```

and it does not work, neither there is a second display on the displays. This might be related to [HDMI from baseus usb-c pd hub wont work on 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302983/hdmi-from-baseus-usb-c-pd-hub-wont-work-on-20-04) where I bought a usb-c hub where the HDMI port won't work. Maybe it's the same reason it does not work for my adapter

Comment: I tend to buy different brands until one works. sometimes they dont

Answer (score 0):

The USB-C hub you have already has an HDMI port?  That's why your HDMI adapter is not working when plugged into it.  Even though the port is not working the hub is still going to filter out the DisplayPort data from the USB-C signal to any USB-C ports the hub has.

USB-C ports have 4 "superspeed" data lanes in it.  To get both USB 3.x data and video through that port the computer and hub will dedicate 2 lanes for USB and 2 lanes for video.  Inside the hub those 2 video lanes will be directed to it's own HDMI port.  A broken HDMI output does not make that video available on the USB-C port, those internal wires are going to run to whatever is broken in the hub.  To get video from the hub will mean resolving whatever issue the hub has.  Plugging in another video adapter downstream will not help.